# How to write type for redux-saga generator function containing yield* delegation in typescript

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I am learning about generators and redux-saga.
I have taken from an existing example which uses yield*.
The first method - yieldPromiseResponse using 'yield' is ok.
The second method - watchPromise which yields the result of yieldPromiseResponse using yield* errors with

> Error: Type 'ForkEffect' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an Iterator

Can someone advise me what type to apply to this example?

```js
const at: TAt = {
  SUCCESS: 'SUCCESS',
};

interface Props {
  username: string;
}

interface GProps {
  payload: Props;
}

type Tprom = (payload: Props) => Promise<string>;

const prom: Tprom = username =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(`resolve prom uesrname = ${username}`);
  });

function* yieldPromiseResponse({ payload }: GProps) {
  /* eslint-disable no-useless-catch */
  try {
    const user = yield call(prom, payload);
    console.log('user = ', user);
    yield put({ type: at.SUCCESS, user });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

function* watchPromise() {
  yield* takeLatest(at.REQUEST, yieldPromiseResponse);
}


export default watchPromise;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this `yield*` stuff so I see the error but I'm not sure of the solution.  If you could link to example that you are basing this on that would help.

Comment: Basically `yield*` needs to be followed by an iterator.  `takeLatest` creates a `ForkEffect` which is not an iterator.

Comment: FYI the variable `username` in your `prom` function is an object with property `username`, not just the username.  You might have meant to destructure `= ({username}) =>`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks for reply. It wasn't that, but I found the answer. Will post

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems here. The first one I have managed to fix.

### Problem 1

1. When removing *

```
yield takeLatest.
```

This causes new error:

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel'.

This is because typescript thinks I'm using takeLatest as channel, not as pattern.
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

- takeLatest(pattern, saga, ..args)
- takeLatest(channel, saga, ..args)

Found the answer for the fix here:
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1286

**Updated code is now recognised in typescript without error**

```js
import { put, call, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { Action } from 'redux';

const ActionTypeRequest = 'REQUEST';

interface Props {
  username: string;
}

interface ActionResult<T> extends Action<string> {
  type: string;
  payload?: T;
}

type Tprom = (payload: Props) => Promise<string>;

const prom: Tprom = payload =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(`resolve prom uesrname = ${payload.username}`);
  });

function* yieldPromiseResponse(action: ActionResult<Props>) {
  /* eslint-disable no-useless-catch */
  const { payload } = action;
  try {
    const user = yield call(prom, payload as Props);

    yield put({ type: ActionTypeRequest, user });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

function* watchPromise() {
  yield takeLatest(ActionTypeRequest, yieldPromiseResponse);
}

export default watchPromise;
```

Problem 2
Still does not work with

```js
  yield* takeLatest(ActionTypeRequest, yieldPromiseResponse);
```

Maybe I need to understand the yield delegation - yield *
When reading this - https://tech.lalilo.com/redux-saga-and-typescript-doing-it-right

When I change my code to this it does not complain.
So maybe someone might be able to explain what is wrong with yield* on my takeLatest method.

```
function* secondaryGenerator() {
  yield delay(111);
  return true;
}

function* watchPromise() {
  yield takeLatest(ActionTypeRequest, yieldPromiseResponse);
  const secondary = yield* secondaryGenerator();
  console.log('second = ', secondary);
}
```